org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest is not accessible
I am using bouncy castle library, and getting not accesible error while importing a class
I am using Java17
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest;

error: The type org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest is not accessible
